# Scheduling the script traversing hdfs directories through Oozie

Tags: shell, hdfs, oozie, mapr

I am working on a **MapR** cluster. I have a script that calls another script like: `source ./../[other directory]/x1.sh`, i.e. the script is calling a script that is in another directory of hdfs.

When I try to schedule it through oozie shell action, the action fails with error:

> ./../[other directory]/x1.sh not found, no such file or directory

I can't change the shell script.

It's working with absolute path but not relative path. Can oozie take relative paths? If oozie can what should I do so that it takes relative paths?

Comment: 1. Check if the user through which Oozie job is triggered has permissions to access that script.
2. Also, check the present working directory of your script which calls the shell script since you're giving relative paths.

Comment: @Samarth I have checked the permissions and the script is working, I have tried manually.

Comment: Can you provide the following information?
1. The path of both the scripts.
2. Output of `ls -lrt` in the directories where both the scripts are present.
3. User with which oozie shell is triggering the job.

Comment: I can't as its an official project but I can provide you the structure: [project path]/ctl/x1.sh and the script calling it (scheduled script) is [project path]/bin/x.sh. Both directories and scripts have same owner and same permissions, i.e as oozie is able to access x.sh, it should have access to x1.sh permission wise

Comment: That should be okay. Mask the sensitive information.

Comment: From which directory are you invoking `x.sh` manually and how did you configure it through Oozie because most likely it seems to be an issue with the relative paths?

Comment: Also, you can try 1 thing to narrow down the problem. You can use absolute path to call your script like `source /absolute/path/of/x1.sh` in `x.sh` and then try to schedule via Oozie. If it works, then it is definitely a relative path problem.

Comment: I am invoking x.sh from [project path]/bin/ I put it in job.properties as a parameter and then pass that parameter as file tag in workflow for shell action

Comment: Can you try with absolute path or perhaps print the `pwd` in `x.sh`?

Comment: It is working with absolute path. Thanks for the help. Have to look at the problem from different perspective now.

Comment: Cool. To do it with relative path, print `pwd` in `x.sh` and then form the relative path as per the `pwd`.

Comment: @Samarth when I use pwd, it shows : /opt/mapr/tmp/hadoop-mapr/nm-local-dir/usercache/.../ctl/x1.sh doesn't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183115/discussion-between-samarth-and-shweta).